# Dynamic Action in Apex - Auto display text field based on Set Value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have two text items. Need to create dynamic action for the following:

1. Order_number
2. Order_type

When a user enters an order number starting with 1, the order type should type should automatically displayed as CONSUMER.

When a user enters an order number starting with 2, the order type should type should automatically displayed as BUSINESS else display null.

Answer (score 1):

Your dynamic action should fire on change of the `ORDER_NUMBER` page item and can contain a PL/SQL action like the one below (could also use a JavaScript action if you are comfortable with it).

[image]